# Save file to server for each user

Tags: php, html, file, save, server

I created website which currently has only login function. I want to make so every user can edit txt file and save it on server. But I want to make it private - user can see only their file. Do you have any ideas what I will need and how it should work? Pseudo code could help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two strategies come into mind for such things:

1. using some soft of file catalog, typically database based, where all files, ownerships and permissions are stored. The process of saving and reading such a file would then be implemented by some controlling script which consults the database for permission considering the authentication credentials collected during the login phase.
2. you could also reserve different parts of the server side file system for each user (say one folder per user). In that case the ownership of files is expressed by its location inside those folders. Access to the files themselves is again granted by some sort of controller script. This is easier to implement at first but obviously less flexible, since you cannot add more features because of the lack of a flexible storage system.

Implementing such system is fine if you want to learn how to program. If this is meant for production use then I would advise against implementing another such system. Look around for an existing solution instead and extend and adapt that for your own purpose. This saves you a lot of time and trouble, since you do not have to repeat all those errors others already did.

I would recommend to take a look at the "owncloud" solution. It is a php based private information system implemented as open source solution. Stable, very flexible, can not only handle but also other things like addresses, calendars and and and. really worth a look: http://owncloud.org

Comment: If I choose second option is it more possible to be hackable? Because there is not protection, just plain get_file from server and it can be easily abused. What do you think?

Comment: This cannot be answered in general, since that does not depend on the approach you use. That is a question of how robust and secure your session management is. The files in such system are _not_ unprotected. As explained they can only be accessed by means of a controlling script. How secure that is depends on your implementation, obviously. That is one of the typical errors I referred to in my last paragraph above...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your need is to save it in a txt file, but if I where you I would store the data in a database, then give the users a "download" link to their txt file, which would create a txt file from their data in the database on the fly.